# Laravel 9 Sail error service "laravel.test" is not running container

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-sail

I have cloned a repository from GitHub, a Laravel project that already has Sail.
Then in order to install composer dependencies, I ran:

```
docker run --rm \
    -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
    -v "$(pwd):/var/www/html" \
    -w /var/www/html \
    laravelsail/php81-composer:latest \
    composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

After that, I ran `sail up`.
All images pulled and built.

Now I have access to the project and its route through the browser, even I can use `sail mysql` commands. However the problem is that when I run `sail artisan` commands, this message shows up:
`service "laravel.test" is not running container #1`.

I am using windows and also `wsl2` which is using `ubuntu 20` as the default Linux distribution.

tip: In another fresh project I do not have any problem with Sail.

I did these things before, but they didn't solve the problem:

- adding `APP_SERVICE=laravel.test` to `.env`.
- running `composer update`.

To clarify my question I will add more codes below.

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  #Laravel App
  app:
    build:
      context: ./docker/php/${DOCKER_PHP_VERSION}
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        xdebug_enabled: ${DOCKER_PHP_XDEBUG_ENABLED}
    image: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    environment:
        XDEBUG_MODE: '${DOCKER_PHP_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - app_network
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - redis
      - meilisearch
      - minio

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - '${DOCKER_NGINX_PORT:-80}:80'
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/nginx/dev/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app_network
    depends_on:
      - app


  # S3 Development
  minio:
    image: 'minio/minio:latest'
    ports:
        - '${DOCKER_MINIO_PORT:-9000}:9000'
        - '${DOCKER_MINIO_CONSOLE_PORT:-8900}:8900'
    environment:
        MINIO_ROOT_USER: 'laravel'
        MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    volumes:
        - 'appminio:/data/minio'
    networks:
        - app_network
    command: minio server /data/minio --console-address ":8900"
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:9000/minio/health/live"]
        retries: 3
        timeout: 5s

  # Laravel Scout Search Provider
  meilisearch:
    image: 'getmeili/meilisearch:latest'
    platform: linux/x86_64
    environment:
      - PUID=${DOCKER_PUID:-1000}
      - PGID=${DOCKER_PGID:-1000}
      - TZ=${DOCKER_TZ:-Australia/Brisbane}
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
        - '${DOCKER_MEILISEARCH_PORT:-7700}:7700'
    volumes:
        - 'appmeilisearch:/data.ms'
    networks:
        - app_network

  # Database
  mysql:
    image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports:
        - '${DOCKER_MYSQL_PORT:-3306}:3306'
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD:-abc123}'
        MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
        MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE:-laravel}'
        MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME:-laravel}'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD:-abc123}'
        MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
        - 'appmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
    networks:
        - app_network
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
        retries: 3
        timeout: 5s

  # Debug emails sent from the app
  mailcatcher:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: dockage/mailcatcher
    environment:
      - PUID=${DOCKER_PUID:-1000}
      - PGID=${DOCKER_PGID:-1000}
      - TZ=${DOCKER_TZ:-Australia/Brisbane}
    ports:
      - "${DOCKER_MAILCATCHER_WEB_PORT:-1080}:1080"
      - "${DOCKER_MAILCATCHER_SMTP_PORT:-1025}:1025"
    networks:
      - app_network

  # Redis Database
  redis:
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "redis-cli", "ping" ]
      interval: 1m
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 30s
    image: redis
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - 'appredis:/data'
    environment:
      - PUID=${DOCKER_PUID:-1000}
      - PGID=${DOCKER_PGID:-1000}
      - TZ=${DOCKER_TZ:-Australia/Brisbane}
    ports:
      - ${DOCKER_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379
    networks:
      - app_network

volumes:
  appredis:
    driver: local
  appmysql:
    driver: local
  appmeilisearch:
    driver: local
  appminio:
    driver: local

networks:
  app_network:
    driver: bridge
```

`.env`:

```
APP_NAME="Boilerplate"
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=my_app_key
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000
FRONTEND_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000
EMAIL_VERIFICATION_REQUIRED=true
TOKEN_ON_REGISTER=false

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=my_database
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=password

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_CONNECTION=localhost

REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailcatcher
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=myemail@test.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

SCOUT_DRIVER=meilisearch
MEILISEARCH_HOST=http://127.0.0.1:7700
MEILISEARCH_KEY=masterKey

#FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=s3
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=access_key
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=pass
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=region
AWS_BUCKET=bucket
AWS_ENDPOINT=http://s3:9000
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=true

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

DOCKER_PUID=1000
DOCKER_PGID=1000
DOCKER_TZ=Australia/Brisbane
DOCKER_NGINX_PORT=8000
DOCKER_REDIS_PORT=6379
DOCKER_MAILCATCHER_WEB_PORT=1080
DOCKER_MAILCATCHER_SMTP_PORT=1025
DOCKER_MEILISEARCH_PORT=7700
DOCKER_MYSQL_PORT=3306
DOCKER_MINIO_PORT=9000
DOCKER_MINIO_CONSOLE_PORT=8900
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=boilerplate
DOCKER_PHP_VERSION=8.1
DOCKER_PHP_XDEBUG_ENABLED=false
DOCKER_PHP_XDEBUG_MODE=develop,debug
```

`composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "Safe Proud API",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0|^8.1|^8.2",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.144",
        "balping/laravel-hashslug": "^2.2",
        "bolechen/nova-activitylog": "^v0.3.0",
        "classic-o/nova-media-library": "^1.0",
        "cloudcake/nova-snowball": "^1.2",
        "dcblogdev/laravel-sent-emails": "^2.0",
        "emilianotisato/nova-tinymce": "^1",
        "eminiarts/nova-tabs": "^1.5",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "johnathan/nova-trumbowyg": "^1.0",
        "kutia-software-company/larafirebase": "^1.3",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.19",
        "laravel/nova": "*",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.0",
        "laravel/scout": "^9.4",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7",
        "laravel/vapor-cli": "^1.13",
        "laravel/vapor-core": "^2.22",
        "laravel/vapor-ui": "^1.5",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~3.0",
        "mpociot/versionable": "^4.3",
        "nnjeim/world": "^1.1",
        "optimistdigital/nova-page-manager": "^3.1",
        "outl1ne/nova-settings": "^3.5",
        "spatie/laravel-activitylog": "^4.5",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^5.0",
        "vinkla/hashids": "^10.0",
        "vyuldashev/nova-permission": "^3.1",
        "whitecube/nova-flexible-content": "^0.2.6",
        "yab/laravel-scout-mysql-driver": "^5.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "./nova"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/Http/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force",
            "@php artisan vapor-ui:publish --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Also, when I run `sail up`:

```
[+] Running 7/0
 ⠿ Container boilerplate-meilisearch-1  Created                        0.0s
 ⠿ Container boilerplate-redis-1        Created                        0.0s
 ⠿ Container boilerplate-minio-1        Created                        0.0s
 ⠿ Container boilerplate-mysql-1        Created                        0.0s
 ⠿ Container boilerplate-mailcatcher-1  Created                        0.0s
 ⠿ Container boilerplate-app-1          Created                        0.0s
 ⠿ Container boilerplate-nginx-1        Created                        0.0s
Attaching to boilerplate-app-1, boilerplate-mailcatcher-1, boilerplate-meilisearch-1, boilerplate-minio-1, boilerplate-mysql-1, boilerplate-nginx-1, boilerplate-redis-1
boilerplate-redis-1        | 1:C 18 Nov 2022 20:44:41.772 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
boilerplate-redis-1        | 1:C 18 Nov 2022 20:44:41.772 # Redis version=7.0.5, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
boilerplate-redis-1        | 1:C 18 Nov 2022 20:44:41.772 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
boilerplate-redis-1        | 1:M 18 Nov 2022 20:44:41.774 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
boilerplate-redis-1        | 1:M 18 Nov 2022 20:44:41.775 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
boilerplate-redis-1        | 1:M 18 Nov 2022 20:44:41.775 # Server initialized
boilerplate-redis-1        | 1:M 18 Nov 2022 20:44:41.775 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
boilerplate-redis-1        | 1:M 18 Nov 2022 20:44:41.776 * Loading RDB produced by version 7.0.5
boilerplate-redis-1        | 1:M 18 Nov 2022 20:44:41.776 * RDB age 53 seconds
boilerplate-redis-1        | 1:M 18 Nov 2022 20:44:41.776 * RDB memory usage when created 0.85 Mb
boilerplate-redis-1        | 1:M 18 Nov 2022 20:44:41.776 * Done loading RDB, keys loaded: 0, keys expired: 0.
boilerplate-redis-1        | 1:M 18 Nov 2022 20:44:41.776 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
boilerplate-redis-1        | 1:M 18 Nov 2022 20:44:41.776 * Ready to accept connections
boilerplate-mailcatcher-1  | Starting MailCatcher v0.8.2
boilerplate-mailcatcher-1  | ==> smtp://0.0.0.0:1025
boilerplate-mysql-1        | [Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 8.0.31-1.2.10-server
boilerplate-meilisearch-1  |
boilerplate-meilisearch-1  | 888b     d888          d8b 888 d8b
                               888
boilerplate-meilisearch-1  | 8888b   d8888          Y8P 888 Y8P
                               888
boilerplate-meilisearch-1  | 88888b.d88888              888
                               888
boilerplate-meilisearch-1  | 888Y88888P888  .d88b.  888 888 888 .d8888b   .d88b.   8888b.  888d888 .d8888b 88888b.
boilerplate-meilisearch-1  | 888 Y888P 888 d8P  Y8b 888 888 888 88K      d8P  Y8b     "88b 888P"  d88P"    888 "88b
boilerplate-meilisearch-1  | 888  Y8P  888 88888888 888 888 888 "Y8888b. 88888888 .d888888 888    888      888  888
boilerplate-meilisearch-1  | 888   "   888 Y8b.     888 888 888      X88 Y8b.     888  888 888    Y88b.    888  888
boilerplate-meilisearch-1  | 888       888  "Y8888  888 888 888  88888P'  "Y8888  "Y888888 888     "Y8888P 888  888
boilerplate-meilisearch-1  |
boilerplate-meilisearch-1  | Database path:             "./data.ms"
boilerplate-meilisearch-1  | Server listening on:       "http://0.0.0.0:7700"
boilerplate-meilisearch-1  | Environment:               "development"
boilerplate-meilisearch-1  | Commit SHA:                "unknown"
boilerplate-meilisearch-1  | Commit date:               "unknown"
boilerplate-meilisearch-1  | Package version:   "0.29.1"
boilerplate-meilisearch-1  |
boilerplate-meilisearch-1  | Thank you for using Meilisearch!
boilerplate-meilisearch-1  |
boilerplate-meilisearch-1  | We collect anonymized analytics to improve our product and your experience. To learn more, including how to turn off analytics, visit our dedicated documentation page: https://docs.meilisearch.com/learn/what_is_meilisearch/telemetry.html
boilerplate-meilisearch-1  |
boilerplate-meilisearch-1  | Anonymous telemetry:       "Enabled"
boilerplate-meilisearch-1  | Instance UID:              "1fa4148e-c0dc-46c7-9f61-f4abb8f0354c"
boilerplate-meilisearch-1  |
boilerplate-meilisearch-1  | No master key found; The server will accept unidentified requests. If you need some protection in development mode, please export a key: export MEILI_MASTER_KEY=xxx
boilerplate-meilisearch-1  |
boilerplate-meilisearch-1  | Documentation:             https://docs.meilisearch.com
boilerplate-meilisearch-1  | Source code:               https://github.com/meilisearch/meilisearch
boilerplate-meilisearch-1  | Contact:           https://docs.meilisearch.com/resources/contact.html
boilerplate-meilisearch-1  |
boilerplate-meilisearch-1  | [2022-11-18T10:44:42Z INFO  actix_server::builder] Starting 4 workers
boilerplate-meilisearch-1  | [2022-11-18T10:44:42Z INFO  actix_server::server] Actix runtime found; starting in Actix runtime
boilerplate-mailcatcher-1  | ==> http://0.0.0.0:1080
boilerplate-mysql-1        | [Entrypoint] Starting MySQL 8.0.31-1.2.10-server
boilerplate-minio-1        | Warning: Default parity set to 0. This can lead to data loss.
boilerplate-minio-1        | MinIO Object Storage Server
boilerplate-minio-1        | Copyright: 2015-2022 MinIO, Inc.
boilerplate-minio-1        | License: GNU AGPLv3 <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.html>
boilerplate-minio-1        | Version: RELEASE.2022-11-11T03-44-20Z (go1.19.3 linux/amd64)
boilerplate-minio-1        |
boilerplate-minio-1        | Status:         1 Online, 0 Offline.
boilerplate-minio-1        | API: http://172.19.0.5:9000  http://127.0.0.1:9000
boilerplate-minio-1        | Console: http://172.19.0.5:8900 http://127.0.0.1:8900
boilerplate-minio-1        |
boilerplate-minio-1        | Documentation: https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/index.html
boilerplate-mysql-1        | 2022-11-18T10:44:42.878570Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
boilerplate-mysql-1        | 2022-11-18T10:44:42.879744Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.
boilerplate-mysql-1        | 2022-11-18T10:44:42.879769Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.31) starting as process 1
boilerplate-mysql-1        | 2022-11-18T10:44:42.886273Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
boilerplate-mysql-1        | 2022-11-18T10:44:43.007089Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
boilerplate-app-1          | Installing Package Dependencies
boilerplate-app-1          | Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
boilerplate-app-1          | Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
boilerplate-app-1          | Nothing to install, update or remove
boilerplate-mysql-1        | 2022-11-18T10:44:43.275853Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
boilerplate-mysql-1        | 2022-11-18T10:44:43.275917Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
boilerplate-app-1          | Package gregoriohc/laravel-nova-theme-responsive is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
boilerplate-app-1          | Generating optimized autoload files
boilerplate-mysql-1        | 2022-11-18T10:44:43.316329Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
boilerplate-mysql-1        | 2022-11-18T10:44:43.316463Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.31'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
boilerplate-nginx-1        | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
boilerplate-nginx-1        | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
boilerplate-nginx-1        | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
boilerplate-nginx-1        | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is not a file or does not exist
boilerplate-nginx-1        | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
boilerplate-nginx-1        | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
boilerplate-nginx-1        | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
boilerplate-nginx-1        | 2022/11/18 10:44:43 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
boilerplate-nginx-1        | 2022/11/18 10:44:43 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.23.2
boilerplate-nginx-1        | 2022/11/18 10:44:43 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 11.2.1 20220219 (Alpine 11.2.1_git20220219)
boilerplate-nginx-1        | 2022/11/18 10:44:43 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
boilerplate-nginx-1        | 2022/11/18 10:44:43 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
boilerplate-nginx-1        | 2022/11/18 10:44:43 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
boilerplate-nginx-1        | 2022/11/18 10:44:43 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 20
boilerplate-nginx-1        | 2022/11/18 10:44:43 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 21
boilerplate-nginx-1        | 2022/11/18 10:44:43 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 22
boilerplate-nginx-1        | 2022/11/18 10:44:43 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 23
boilerplate-nginx-1        | 2022/11/18 10:44:43 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 24
boilerplate-nginx-1        | 2022/11/18 10:44:43 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 25
boilerplate-nginx-1        | 2022/11/18 10:44:43 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 26
boilerplate-nginx-1        | 2022/11/18 10:44:43 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 27
boilerplate-minio-1        |
boilerplate-minio-1        |  You are running an older version of MinIO released 6 days ago
boilerplate-minio-1        |  Update: Run `mc admin update`
boilerplate-minio-1        |
boilerplate-minio-1        |
boilerplate-app-1          | Class App\Http\Resources\Api\v1\AddressResource located in ./app/Http/Resources/Api/V1/AddressResource.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
boilerplate-app-1          | > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
boilerplate-app-1          | > @php artisan package:discover --ansi
boilerplate-app-1          |
boilerplate-app-1          |    INFO  Discovering packages.
boilerplate-app-1          |
boilerplate-app-1          |   bolechen/nova-activitylog ............................................. DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |   classic-o/nova-media-library .......................................... DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |   cloudcake/nova-fixed-bars ............................................. DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |   cloudcake/nova-snowball ............................................... DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |   dcblogdev/laravel-sent-emails ......................................... DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |   emilianotisato/nova-tinymce ........................................... DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |   eminiarts/nova-tabs ................................................... DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |   gregoriohc/laravel-nova-theme-responsive .............................. DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |   intervention/image .................................................... DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |   johnathan/nova-trumbowyg .............................................. DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |   kutia-software-company/larafirebase ................................... DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |   laravel/nova .......................................................... DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |   laravel/sail .......................................................... DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |   laravel/sanctum ....................................................... DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |   laravel/scout ......................................................... DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |   laravel/tinker ........................................................ DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |   laravel/ui ............................................................ DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |   laravel/vapor-core .................................................... DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |   laravel/vapor-ui ...................................................... DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |   mpociot/versionable ................................................... DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |   nesbot/carbon ......................................................... DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |   nnjeim/world .......................................................... DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |   nunomaduro/collision .................................................. DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |   nunomaduro/termwind ................................................... DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |   optimistdigital/nova-locale-field ..................................... DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |   optimistdigital/nova-page-manager ..................................... DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |   optimistdigital/nova-translations-loader .............................. DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |   outl1ne/nova-settings ................................................. DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |   spatie/laravel-activitylog ............................................ DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |   spatie/laravel-ignition ............................................... DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |   spatie/laravel-permission ............................................. DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |   vinkla/hashids ........................................................ DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |   vyuldashev/nova-permission ............................................ DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |   whitecube/nova-flexible-content ....................................... DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |   yab/laravel-scout-mysql-driver ........................................ DONE
boilerplate-app-1          |
boilerplate-app-1          | 100 packages you are using are looking for funding.
boilerplate-app-1          | Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
boilerplate-app-1          | Running database migrations
boilerplate-app-1          |
boilerplate-app-1          |    INFO  Nothing to migrate.
boilerplate-app-1          |
boilerplate-app-1          | Linking Storage
boilerplate-app-1          |
boilerplate-app-1          |    ERROR  The [public/storage] link already exists.
boilerplate-app-1          |
boilerplate-app-1          | Generating IDE Helper Stubs
boilerplate-app-1          |
boilerplate-app-1          |    ERROR  There are no commands defined in the "ide-helper" namespace.
boilerplate-app-1          |
boilerplate-app-1          |
boilerplate-app-1          |    ERROR  There are no commands defined in the "ide-helper" namespace.
boilerplate-app-1          |
boilerplate-app-1          | 2022-11-18 10:44:49,582 INFO Set uid to user 0 succeeded
boilerplate-app-1          | 2022-11-18 10:44:49,584 INFO supervisord started with pid 39
boilerplate-app-1          | 2022-11-18 10:44:50,586 INFO spawned: 'php' with pid 40
boilerplate-app-1          | [18-Nov-2022 10:44:50] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 40
boilerplate-app-1          | [18-Nov-2022 10:44:50] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
boilerplate-app-1          | 2022-11-18 10:44:51,610 INFO success: php entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
boilerplate-nginx-1        | 172.19.0.1 - - [18/Nov/2022:10:45:13 +0000] "GET /admin/dashboard HTTP/1.1" 200 17616 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
boilerplate-app-1          | 172.19.0.8 -  18/Nov/2022:10:45:13 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
boilerplate-nginx-1        | 172.19.0.1 - - [18/Nov/2022:10:45:16 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 17601 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
boilerplate-app-1          | 172.19.0.8 -  18/Nov/2022:10:45:16 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
```

Answer (score 15):

I found the solution.

After looking at this part of `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  #Laravel App
  app:
    build:
      context: ./docker/php/${DOCKER_PHP_VERSION}
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        xdebug_enabled: ${DOCKER_PHP_XDEBUG_ENABLED}
    image: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    working_dir: /var/www/html
```

I realized that Laravel service has a different name which in this project is `app`.
So in `.env` file, I added this:

```
APP_SERVICE=app
```

Comment: That was it for me too! I just changed the service name back to laravel.test in my `docker-compose.yml` though to save needed to add another env variable.